# Change Order status automatically when product is delivered based on fedex

Tags: magento-1.9, fedex

I want to change the order status based on fedex or aramex shipping method.

Suppose fedex delivered product i want just automatically update order status in my system.

i have used fedex shipping as well as shipment api. but its not return satisfy response.

here is my code : but i cant get the final status from fedex.

```
$response = Mage::getModel('usa/shipping_carrier_fedex')->getTracking($data[$i]['track_number']);
                $trackings = $response->getTrackings()->getData('progressdetails');
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($trackings);
                exit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<code>
$response = Mage::getModel('usa/shipping_carrier_fedex')->getTracking('track_number');
$trackData = $response->getAllTrackings();
$progressData = $trackData[0]->getData('progressdetail');
$deliveredStatus = $progressData[0]['activity'];
</code>
```

its working for me.